# jsPDF: unnecessary spaces in generated pdf file

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF to convert an html element to pdf but for some reason, the generated pdf contains  an unnecessary spaces.

I can't use the html2canvas as I need pdf with textually format (and not an image)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Font issue, just use the default font

Comment: Ah that's amazing, thank you so much! Appreciate the response my dude, have some upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

It's a font issue; just set your HTML content to load a system font.